# How to find out the current state of the program - Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I can not cope with the search for this issue - how can I find out whether the program is currently active or in the background?
help me who knows it! thank you.

Comment: Just intercept the application suspend and resume events. Set a flag.

Comment: @dashman thank you! I've already found a solution to this problem